# How do I set Multipart Boundaries ubuntu 20.04

Tags: php, ubuntu

I just upgraded my servers to ubuntu 20.04
Software the worked with the current php (7.4) now doesnt
I am getting FILES error 3 because of modsecurity
It is because when i do a file upload i get

```
Multipart parsing error: Multipart: Final boundary missing
```

I am pretty sure its a setting I am not seeing
Any ideas
so far I did

```
a2enmod headers

a2enmod mime_magic

[Wed Apr 14 06:51:49.408489 2021] [:error] [pid 45290] [client 96.225.42.186:62939] ModSecurity: Warning. Matched "Operator `Eq' with parameter `0' against variable `REQBODY_ERROR' (Value: `1' ) [file "/etc/modsecurity3/modsecurity.d/modsecurity.conf"] [line "53"] [id "200002"] [rev ""] [msg "Failed to parse request body."] [data "Multipart parsing error: Multipart: Final boundary missing."] [severity "2"] [ver ""] [maturity "0"] [accuracy "0"] [hostname "www.simplifiedchurch.net"] [uri "/sc/603af891cf463b33c286c37e21ecddc4/expenses_ajax/doajaxAUTOfileupload.php"] [unique_id "161839750873.019595"] [ref "v1152,1v1152,1v1152,1v1152,1v1152,1v1152,1v1152,1v1152,1v1152,1v1152,1v1152,1v1152,1v1152,1v1152,1v1152,1v1152,1v1152,1v1152,1v1152,1v1152,1v1152,1v1152,1v1152,1v1152,1v1152,1v1152,1v1152,1v1152,1v115 (80 characters omitted)"], referer: https://website.net/sc/603af891cf463b33c286c37e21ecddc4/55a591650f223bc6074c23240d3bb4b1.php
[Wed Apr 14 06:51:49.408680 2021] [:error] [pid 45290] [client 96.225.42.186:62939] ModSecurity: Warning. Matched "Operator `Eq' with parameter `0' against variable `REQBODY_ERROR' (Value: `1' ) [file "https://rules.malware.expert/download.php?rules=generic"] [line "23"] [id "400000"] [rev ""] [msg "Malware Expert - Failed to parse request body: Multipart parsing error: Multipart: Final boundary missing."] [data ""] [severity "0"] [ver ""] [maturity "0"] [accuracy "0"] [hostname "www.website.net"] [uri "/sc/603af891cf463b33c286c37e21ecddc4/expenses_ajax/doajaxAUTOfileupload.php"] [unique_id "161839750873.019595"] [ref "v1152,1v1152,1v1152,1v1152,1v1152,1v1152,1v1152,1v1152,1v1152,1v1152,1v1152,1v1152,1v1152,1v1152,1v1152,1v1152,1v1152,1v1152,1v1152,1v1152,1v1152,1v1152,1v1152,1v1152,1v1152,1v1152,1v1152,1v1152,1v115 (80 characters omitted)"], referer: https://website.net/sc/603af891cf463b33c286c37e21ecddc4/55a591650f223bc6074c23240d3bb4b1.php

<script type="text/javascript">
$('#myfiles').live("change",function(){  
var theDate=$("#datepicker").val();
if(theDate.length<'1'){
$("#datepicker").css({'background-color' : '#FF6347'});
$('.uploadInstructions').html("<font color='red'><b><big>SELECT A DATE BEFORE UPLOADING IMAGES</b></big></font>");

return;
}
                    var myfiles = document.getElementById("myfiles");
                    var files = myfiles.files; 
                    var data = new FormData();
                    data.append('voucher_id', $("#voucher_id").val());
            var theDate=$("#datepicker").val();

            data.append('date', theDate);
data.append('iphone', '0');
            data.append('year', $("#element_16").val());
                    for (i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                        data.append('file' + i, files[i]);
                    }
$("#main_page_div").mask_div("Processing Images..."); 


                    $.ajax({
                        url: 'expenses_ajax/doajaxAUTOfileupload.php',
                        type: 'POST',
                        contentType: false,
                        data: data,
                        processData: false,
                        cache: false
                    }).done(function(msg) {
                    $("#main_page_div").unmask_div();
                  
            var vid=$('#vid', msg).text();
            $("#voucher_id").val(vid);
var imageTable=$('#images', msg).html();
$("#image_div").html('');
            $("#image_div").html(imageTable);

                    });





                  
                });

</script>
```

Comment: Quite hard to understand your question.  Can you edit and include the exact errors you are seeing?  Some punctuation might help clarify your problem too.

Comment: Is there any code involved you could share?

Comment: I updated the question with the jquery code

Answer (score 0):

OWASP ModSecurity Core Rule Set project here.

With CT "undefined" you run the risk of bypassing the ModSecurity WAF. The way you have set it up, ModSec no longer detects this as multipart / MIME upload.

A correct CT would be (e.g.) "multipart/form-data; boundary=------------------------427918cb879af9d2".
And then the boundaries set correctly. However you should not be doing this yourself. There are libraries meant to do this for you. The way you do it, you construct a backdoor into your application.

Comment: could you steer me to a proper library?
Im feeling like something was not loaded with ubuntu 20.04 because 18 I had zero problems

Comment: Sorry, but I am not a PHP developer.